# How to specify public port to receive tcp connections with ngrok

Tags: ngrok

I have access to the paid plan on ngrok. I want to have port 9000 open on a public domain.

What I have now:

```
Session Status                online
Account                       ... (Plan: Pro)
Version                       2.3.35
Region                        United States (us)
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    tcp://6.tcp.ngrok.io:19004 -> localhost:9000

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

What I want:

```
Session Status                online
Account                       ... (Plan: Pro)
Version                       2.3.35
Region                        United States (us)
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    tcp://whatever.ngrok.io:9000 -> localhost:9000  <= public port is 9000

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

I can create my own subdomain like foobar.eu.ngrok.io, how do I reuse that and open the port 9000 on it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this from the docs?

`ngrok tcp --region=us --remote-addr 1.tcp.ngrok.io:20301 22`

### Listening on a reserved remote address

> Normally, the remote address and port is assigned randomly each time you start a TCP tunnel. For production services (and convenience) you often want a stable, guaranteed remote address. To do this, first, log in to your ngrok.com dashboard and click "Reserve Address" in the "Reserved TCP Addresses" section. Then use the -remote-addr option when invoking ngrok to bind a tunnel on your reserved TCP address. Make sure the -region you specify matches the region in which you reserved your address.

Reference: https://ngrok.com/docs#tcp-remote-addr

Comment: No that only uses 9000 on localhost. And I want tcp, not http.

Comment: `{port} will be assigned when you create the address.` I don't want a random port, I need 9000

Comment: Yes, *normally* it is assigned randomly but you can reserve the address in your dashboard and use that

Comment: Ok but how do I do that? I looked everywhere in the dashboard and I tried everything and I could not do it.

Comment: Same issue here, I've opened a support ticket in the hopes they can assign it manually. The "will be assigned" isn't very helpful when you want to use a specific port for the outside party.